# Gradle build completed successfully but Android Studio cannot resolve dependencies

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've a weird case where gradle builds OK, but Android Studio's editor cannot resolve dependencies.
External classes references appear in red and I cannot <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+click on these classes to see the source.

Any idea how to solve this ?

I'm using Android Studio 3.1 and gradle 4.4

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the latest Gradle version is 4.6... You might want to try and update it.

Comment: I've upgraded gradle to version 4.6 but it didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those interested, I solved the problem as follows:

- removed the files in the project 's .idea\libraries
- menu File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...
- menu Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: Have you tried to force a gradle Sync ? To do that, just add a new line to your project's build.gradle, such as //test, and hit "Sync Now"

Comment: i fund that when i install kotlin plugin this problem come out

Comment: How about you use Java only ?